# Normalization, division and reshaping processes on an HDF5 file

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I performing a set of division operations and reshaping on a HDF5 file. As my datapoints is around 4000 in number it takes around a minute. I will be adding more data, which will further slow my overall code execution time.
How can I optimize this code to make it faster?

```
def pre_proc_data():
    jointMatrix = np.array([], dtype=np.float64).reshape(0, 500 * 17)
    hdf5_file = h5py.File("/home/Data.hdf5")

    for j in range(len(hdf5_file["vector"])):
        # Normalization
        norm_vec = hdf5_file["vector"][j]
        norm_vec[:, 0] = (norm_vec[:, 0] - (-3.059)) / 6.117  # W0 - Left and right
        norm_vec[:, 5] = (norm_vec[:, 5] - (-3.059)) / 6.117
        norm_vec[:, 1] = (norm_vec[:, 1] - (-1.5707)) / 3.6647  # W1 
        norm_vec[:, 6] = (norm_vec[:, 6] - (-1.5707)) / 3.6647
        norm_vec[:, 2] = (norm_vec[:, 2] - (-3.059)) / 6.117  # W2 
        norm_vec[:, 14] = (norm_vec[:, 14] - (-3.059)) / 6.117
        norm_vec[:, 3] = (norm_vec[:, 3] - (-1.7016)) / 3.4033  # S0 
        norm_vec[:, 10] = (norm_vec[:, 10] - (-1.7016)) / 3.4033
        norm_vec[:, 4] = (norm_vec[:, 4] - (-2.147)) / 3.194  # s1 
        norm_vec[:, 8] = (norm_vec[:, 8] - (-2.147)) / 3.194

        norm_vec[:, 11] = (norm_vec[:, 11] - (-3.0541)) / 6.1083  # eo 
        norm_vec[:, 15] = (norm_vec[:, 15] - (-3.0541)) / 6.1083
        norm_vec[:, 12] = (norm_vec[:, 12] - (-0.05)) / 2.67  # e1 
        norm_vec[:, 16] = (norm_vec[:, 16] - (-0.05)) / 2.67

        reshaped_vec = hdf5_file["vector"][j].reshape(500 * 17)
        jointMatrix = np.vstack((jointMatrix, reshaped_vec))

    return jointMatrix


jointMatrix = pre_proc_data()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all your code could be vectorized with the help of [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

At first, instead of using all these `norm_vec[:, ...] = ...` you could create two vectors of length `17` containing values you use to normalize the data.

I assume normalizing values to be mean and standard deviation (please tell me if I'm wrong), so I'll be calling them `mean` and `std` correspondingly.

`mean` is a `np.ndarray` with values `[-3.059, -1.5707, ..., -0.05]` and `std` is a `np.ndarray` with values `[6.117, 3.6647, ..., 2.67]` (indicies ranging from zero to 16).

Using this notation, for loop could be rewritten:

```
for j in range(len(hdf5_file["vector"])):

        norm_vec = (hdf5_file["vector"][j] - mean) / std

        reshaped_vec = norm_vec.reshape(500 * 17)
        jointMatrix = np.vstack((jointMatrix, reshaped_vec))
```

This should give a certain speed-up. However, the code could be further optimized by vectorizing the loop itself.

The whole code now looks like this:

```
def pre_proc_data():

    hdf5_file = h5py.File("/home/Data.hdf5")
    norm_vec = (hdf5_file["vector"] - mean) / std
    # from 3d to 2d
    return norm_vec.reshape(-1, 500 * 17)

jointMatrix = pre_proc_data()
```